# local isomorphism of modules

Tags: commutative-algebra, modules

Let $S=\mathbb{C}[x_1,\cdots ,x_n]$ be the polynomial ring, and let $M$ and $N$ be $S$-modules. Suppose that the localizations $M_{x_{i}}\cong N_{x_{i}}$ are isomorphic for all $i$. Is it true that $M\cong N$? If not, is it true if I further assume that there is a nonzero global morphism $M\to N$ that induces the isomorphisms $M_{x_i}\to N_{x_i}$?

Comment: @EricWofsey good point. I modified the question to address this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No.  For instance, if $M=\mathbb{C}$ with $x_i$ acting trivially on $M$ for all $i$, then $M_{x_i}=0$ for all $i$, so the map $M\to 0$ induces isomorphisms after localizing at each $x_i$ but $M\not\cong 0$.

More generally, let $A$ be a commutative ring and $T\subseteq A$.  You could ask whether if a map $f:M\to N$ of $A$-modules induces isomorphisms $M_t\to N_t$ for each $t\in T$, then $f$ must be an isomorphism.  The answer is yes iff the ideal $I$ generated by $T$ is all of $A$.

To prove this, suppose $I\neq A$.  Then if $M=A/I$, we have $M_t=0$ for all $t\in T$ the map $M\to 0$ induces an isomorphism after localizing at any $t\in T$ but is not an isomorphism.

Conversely, suppose $f:M\to N$ is not an isomorphism but induces isomorphisms $M_t\to N_t$ for each $t\in T$.  Then either the kernel or cokernel of $f$ is nontrivial; let us suppose the kernel $K$ of $f$ is nontrivial (the cokernel case is similar).  Since localization is exact and $M_t\to N_t$ is an isomorphism for each $t\in T$, $K_t=0$ for each $t\in T$.  Fixing some nonzero element $k\in K$ and letting $J$ be the annihilator of $k$, this means that for each $t\in T$, $t^n\in J$ for some $n$.  That is, $I\subseteq \sqrt{J}$.  But since $k\neq 0$, $J$ is a proper ideal, so $\sqrt{J}$ is also a proper ideal, so $I$ is a proper ideal.